# faux-spirational lingo

Tags: phrase-meaning

> Their real product, Montell insists, “isn’t merchandise, it’s rhetoric.” Today’s MLMs use the language of empowerment to entice women to join. Phrases like “Build a fempire” and “Be a mompreneur” and other “**faux-spirational lingo** of commodified fourth wave feminism,” Montell writes, abound in their promotional materials. Like cults, they utilize terminology that distinguishes and elevates their business model compared to traditional employers’. For instance, you will not have a boss but rather “an upline mentor,” and sellers are not employees but rather “entrepreneurs.” People with salaried positions, benefits, and other basic labor protections, on the other hand, are said, with derision, to possess a “J.O.B.” (jackass of a boss). In this way, sellers aren’t buying oils or diet pills but life rafts. With enough esoteric Facebook posts about “opportunities” and creepy D.M.s to old high school classmates, they believe they can transcend the conditions of the working poor to become “boss babes.”
> Source: [New Republic](https://newrepublic.com/article/162856/spot-cult-cultish-language-fanaticism-review)

I understand "faux-spirational lingo" as "foreign language that sounds inspirational yet is actually not inspirational." Am I on the right track?

Comment: Whether it inspires anybody is impossible to say. It dresses itself up in dubious colours that some may find inspirational. That is, it's marketing ideas!

Comment: 'faux' - prefix is mainly American usage and implies falsity or fakeness, and does not mean anything about foreign language.

Comment: I think you are on the right track except for "foreign" - there's nothing foreign about the words.

Comment: "Today’s MLMs" no, it's a technique that has been used for decades. Throw in a few pseudo-scientific buzzwords to complete the pitch.

Comment: Not a foreign language, but the jargon used by these organisations.

Comment: I think "faux-spirational" is at least as ugly as "fempire" and "mompreneur". (Maybe that's what the author was going for.)

Comment: Yup, it's just the usual MLM stuff, but remember the subtext -- the New Republic views individual effort or success in the worst possible way. If the poor got money, there would be less poor for the New Republic readers to help.